# MySQL - Update with select query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tables : subnets and locations

I'm trying to do a sql query with an update and a select. I need to update some rows with information from another table, but there is nothing that can actually join the two tables...
I'm having some difficulties.

Here's the query :

```
UPDATE subnets
SET place = (SELECT locations.id FROM subnets, locations
WHERE LEFT(locations.name,4) LIKE 
LEFT (subnets.description,4))
WHERE subnets.network='192.168.1.9';
```

I'd like to get the id of the second table that have common information with a column from my first table....

Tell me if you don't understand something.

Thank you

Comment: What does not work? Provide some example data.

Comment: The error is something like the following :
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'subnets' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Ah, yes, see it: You can't select and update the same table. The answer below fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join

```
UPDATE subnets
inner join locations on LEFT(locations.name,4) LIKE LEFT (subnets.description,4)
    AND subnets.network='192.168.1.9'
 SET place = locations.id
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip scaisEdge, I'll try it tomorrow morning and I'll tell you !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much all, that works well !
I now have another situation :

```
UPDATE subnets dt1, subnets dt2
SET dt1.masterSubnetId = dt2.id
WHERE LEFT(dt2.description,4) LIKE 'OF20' AND dt2.network='0';
```

What I'm trying to do is the following :
I have a table subnets with a column id, and a column masterSubnetId.
I want to update the value of masterSubnetId of a row to specify the id of another row.

For example, if I have a row that describes the subnet named FRANCE, and another row that describes the subnet named PARIS, I want PARIS to have as masterSubnetId value the id of "FRANCE" subnet.
These two subnets and rows are in the same table, so I don't think I have to join anything...

The two conditions would be if the first 4 characters of the description field are equals, and if the network value is equal to 0.

I'm having trouble in creating the query.

Feel free to ask me if you want further information.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your second question. ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/44843974/1000756 ) It wasn't completely clear to me, as you mentioned example and then conditions, but maybe you can try

```
update subnets as dt1
inner join (
select id from subnets where subnetName = 'FRANCE') as dt2
set dt1.masterSubnetid = dt2.id
where dt1.subnetName = 'PARIS'
```